# not able to assign dropdown select value in angularjs controller.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, drop-down-menu, scope

I find it a bit weird about the problem i am facing. here it is.

HTML

```
<div>
     <select ng-model="params.select" ng-change="View($event)">
           <option value="" disabled>-</option>
           <option value="table1">Table 1</option>
           <option value="table2">Table 2</option>
           <option value="table3">Table 3</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.View = function ($event) {
  if($scope.params.select =='table1') {
     console.log('table 1 is selected');
  }
```

In the above code, if i check whether the dropdown value is table1, i am able to check that. this works fine.

However, if i try to initialize it. for e.g.

```
$scope.params.select = 'table1'
```

It gives an error in the console view stating 'Cannot set property 'select' of undefined. Can someone highlight me please where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `$scope.params` is defined and an object:

```
$scope.params = {}
$scope.params.select = 'table1'
```

or define and set all at once:

```
$scope.params = {select: 'table1'}
```